# Proactive security on Internet exposed small server

Tags: linux, ssh, security

I have a small server in cloud, which I am using for my testing purposes. I have been concerned about security on this small server from the very beginning. That is why I did not configured anything there yet, except sshd. I configured it in a bit paranoid mode, just to be safe then sorry.

Before taking a final snapshot with basic configuration, I decided to check the logs. Despite I did not use my server for anything yet, I found my logs full of unsuccessful authorization attempts. Connections were made around the world without any particular distribution in geography, or any other system. Within 24 hours I got 10MB logs with all sorts of scan attempts. Now I don't know what is the state and what is happening to my small server. If my particular version of sshd is susceptible to some 0-day exploit, I could already run a rooted system, which makes all snapshots pointless.

I could develop a set of system security scripts.

First, which comes to my mind, is SHA256 sum of all files on my system. I can run a small daemon, which could traverse my system and check sums. If anything change - it may let me know in some way. If there are changes in kernel, /bin, /sbin, /lib hierarchies - I could prevent system even from booting. It is might be safer to restore system from backup, rather then sharing my personal data with some unknown authorities on Internet.

Second tool, which comes to my mind, is proactive monitoring of /var/log/auth.log. If I see some address, which is trying to contact some of my facilities more then few times, I can block that address with internal firewall, or shutdown the system if I see something really unusual.

I am comfortable with wide set of programming languages, but I really don't want to go too deep and spend more then one-two days for such development. This limits set of possible alternatives to Perl and Python. I don't see a shell script viable here.

So,

1. Is this normal to see such number of attacks on newly configured server?
2. Is there any Internet resource, where I can see if any component of my system is in 0-day danger?
3. Is first and second tools could be efficient for keeping my system safe and clean?
4. Is it fine from resources usage point of view to use Perl or Python for such security solutions?

--
Regards,
Paul

Comment: Yes, these attacks are "normal":) [Server management](https://serverfault.com/) is a site all by itself. Basic rules: no passwords, use SSH keys, use a firewall (UFW or else) to lock up all ports except those you need (SSH, HTTP...)(and throttle the SSH one), no homegrown solutions, unless you are an expert they usually do more harm than good. You can install `fail2ban` to automatically ban IP addresses that appear too often in logs. Beyond this,security depends on the specific software that you use.

Comment: I read about fail2ban, but I thought it is more complex, then I need. Anyway, it should be no problem to get it working. I am a bit concerned about resources on my small server. It is a virtual machine with shared cpu/memory. If fail2ban is heavy - I will sufficiently degrade this machine performance.

Comment: Fail2ban isn't heavy. I use it in a fairly small server (512MB). Likely pays for itself due to all connection attempts that are rejected outright. But don't presuppose things. In matters of security, the best security is to admit that you don't know anything:)